# R encoutered a fatal error and terminate; after I export 500GB data and can't read any files since then

Tags: r, parallel-processing, ram, terminate

I tried to process batch of Himawari-8 data and export them to the tif files I want. The codes I used are as below:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
library(DoParallel)
library(foreach)

lst <- list.files(path="D:\\0619\\",pattern='nc$',full.names=TRUE)
detectCores()

usecores <- detectCores-10
cl <- makeCluster(usecores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i =1:143) %dopar% {
  library(raster)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  library(ncdf4) 
  library(rgdal)
  nc<-nc_open(lst[3])
  r1<-raster(lst[i],
             var='albedo_01')
  r2<-raster(lst[i],
             var='albedo_02')
  r3<-raster(lst[i],
             var='albedo_03')
  r4<-raster(lst[i],
             var='albedo_04')
  
  rg <-0.6321*r2+0.2928*r3+0.0715*r4
  rr <- brick(r3,rg,r1)
  name <- strsplit(lst[i],"\\_")
  tifname <- paste("H8_VIS_",name[[1]][3], "_",name[[1]][4],"_FLDK",sep="")
  rw <- writeRaster(rr,filename = paste("E:\\H8_VIS_data\\20190619\\", tifname, ".tif", sep=""),
                    format = 'GTiff')
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

This code works on my PC and export nearly 500GB data. One day, it went wrong and report error

```
R encoutered a fatal error
The session was terminated
```

I looked for solutions, tried to uninstall R and RStudio, delete any R files I can find, restart PC and install R & RStudio in conda.
Then, it works for a well. After I process two H-8 netcdf data(600MB each). R crashed again and reported the same error.
####################################################################

I thought it's my PC doesn't have enough RAM, so I run this on a very high performance computer. After about 500GB data are exported, R report a error:

```
error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]): error reading from connection
```

Then I stop to run code in parallel, after export two result, R crashed and show

```
R encoutered a fatal error
The session was terminated
```

And the R on this high performance computer cannot work anymore. I used `gc()` and it doesn't work. I think during my data process, some garbage stored in somewhere and they exceed R's storage.

Please tell me how to fix this problem. Thank you very much!

#######

I just find out that, read raster from a one file will not terminate.

```
r1 <- raster("D:/0619/h8_201906190000.nc",var = 'albedo_1')
```

While reading files from a list will terminate. (I didn't call for parallelization this time. It just blowed up because of these two code.)

```
list <- list.files(path="D:\\0619\\",pattern='nc$',full.names=TRUE)
r1 <- raster(list[1],var = 'albedo_1')
```

Comment: Guessin `G` should be `Gb` or `GiB`.  and `M` is `MiB` or `Mb`. Your problem arrives at the same stage of your program every time, and it is impossible to guess exactly what is happening from the error message. This is the stage for [debugging](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) and for that hadley's book [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Just a comment regarding your parallelisation strategy: you just use `1:143` in your loop, but export `lst` to every worker. If `lst` is a large file, this can lead to problems. Try to only export the list entry of `lst` you need to the respective worker, you can do this by using `itertools` in the `foreach` loop

Comment: thank you Oliver. It's GB and MB I'm talking about. I think debug requires run the former code, while my R and RStudio crashed down in the very begining.

Comment: @starja Hi, I think that's the reason R crashed at first. Do you know how to fix it? I can read files from list right now. R will terminate.

Comment: sorry, it's called `iterators`. Have a look at the vignettes: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/vignettes/iterators.pdf

Comment: @starja Thank you posting the link. I learned how to fix the iteration, however, my R and RStudio seems broken. It can't import files from a list now. Any idea about this?